# Internet connection keeps dropping after update

Tags: networking, wireless, updates

After a manual update on my system a couple of days ago I'm loosing my internet connection every few minutes. I've got dual boot and Windows does not seem affected, so I'm pretty sure the hardware is all fine.  I've tried using my phone as a hotspot with similar results, which reinforces my impression that it's the update causing the problem.

I'm running 22.04 on an ASUS F510QA. Please let me know what else you need for a diagnosis.

Thanks in advance.